# Drag-and-drop file onto executable in Quick Launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, drag-and-drop

I wish to drag files from Nautilus onto a certain executable (`.desktop` file) in my Unity quick launcher (so that the executable file will run with the path of the dragged file as its first argument).

I find this behaviour works fine when I drag a file from Nautilus onto the `.desktop` file in another Nautilus window, but when I try to drag the file onto the quick launcher, my executable becomes disabled. Is there a remedy?

[image]

Comment: What you're showing on the screenshot is pdf file, not `.desktop`. Simply dragging and dropping to launcher should work.  I've several `.desktop` files that I pinned to my launcher by the same method

Comment: @Serg, I'm not trying to drag a `.desktop` onto the launcher; I'm trying to drag a data/text file onto a `.desktop` (executable) file in the launcher.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean. Is there a particular program that doesn't work or just all programs on the launcher don't allow dragging and dropping  ? I've noticed although LibreOffice Writer doesn't light-up with I drag text files onto it, but it still does open the file i dragged.  Have you tried dropping the file onto the icon despite it not lighting up ?

Comment: Only launcher items that have the same mimetype in their .desktop file as the file being dragged will stay active. To see with a .pdf add evince (Document Viewer) to the unity launcher, when dragging a pdf it will remain active. So check the Mimetype= line in the .desktop of the launcher item you want active for pdf mimetypes listed (or any other file/mime

Comment: Thanks, @doug. I added `MimeType=text/*;application/*;` to my `.desktop` file, and it now supports drag-and-drop for the files that I wanted.